# cannot install php5.6-zip on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-extension, php-ziparchive

currently I want to update my old **php 5.6 application** in **ubuntu xenial 16.04.6** with **php5.6-zip** extension.

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip`

> E: Unable to locate package php5.6-zip
>  E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.6-zip'
>  E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-zip'

tried to add the ppa repository `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`

> The user named '~ondrej' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/php5-5.6'

Then tried to run `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php` and
`sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip`

still got the unable to locate package php5.6-zip error. Btw there is no php5.6-zip from `apt-cache policy php5.6` command. Does anyone have solution regarding this problem? your help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: PHP 5.6 is horribly outdated, and Ubuntu Xenial is also unsupported. You should plan to upgrade both as soon as possible

Comment: unfortunately there are many existing application in the server so to upgrade the ubuntu version will cost much resource. thank you for your concern

Comment: Then have a look at https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1567 - the maintainer of these packages provided alternatives you should check

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know you can't install from zip using `"apt-get install"`. Since the zip file contains the build files. To install it use this instead, this should work.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6
```

And this to see versions

```
php -v
```

Comment: "you can't install from zip" - what do you mean by that? `apt-get install php5.6-zip` looks like a pretty valid statement

Comment: But it isn't apt-get install, installs from a repo not a file. To install from zip. Extract it and and then build and install it.

Comment: What do you mean by "install from zip"? What makes you think that anything in the original question installs "from zip"?

Comment: Srry misread tought he wanted to install from zip :(